# Durandal Load data when view is still loading

Tags: durandal

Currently I have a method in the activate method that gets data from a rest service, the problem is that the view is waiting for the promise to be finished, how can I load the view AND get the data without blocking the activate method

```
var activate = function() {
     datacontext.PersonData().then(function(result) {
            name(result.person.firstName + " " + result.person.lastName);
            if (result.person.gender != undefined) {
                sex("(" + result.person.gender.substr(0, 1) + ")");
            }
            dob(generalFunctions.convertTimeStamp(result.person.birthDate, false));
            inss(result.person.inss);
        }); 
}

return { activate: activate }
```

The full code -->

```
define(['durandal/app',
    'knockout',
    'core/config',
    'services/datacontext',
    'core/generalFunctions'],
function (app, ko, config, datacontext, generalFunctions) {
var name = ko.observable();
var sex = ko.observable();
var dob = ko.observable();
var inss = ko.observable();
var address = ko.observable();
var city = ko.observable();
var phone = ko.observable();
var personIsSelected = ko.observable(false);
var personIsNotSelected = ko.observable(false);
var activate = function (id) {
    config.isLoading(false);
    if (id == null) {
        if (config.selectedPatientId().length == 0) {
            personIsNotSelected(true);
            personIsSelected(false);
        } else {
            personIsNotSelected(false);
            personIsSelected(true);
        }
    } else {
        config.selectedPatientId(id);
        personIsSelected(true);
        personIsNotSelected(false);
    }
    config.pageTitle("Dashboard");
    setDashboardData();
};


var setDashboardData = function () {
    var id = config.selectedPatientId();
    //Fill basc patient data

    datacontext.patientBasicData(id).then(function(result) {
        name(result.person.firstName + " " + result.person.lastName);
        if (result.person.gender != undefined) {
            sex("(" + result.person.gender.substr(0, 1) + ")");
        }
        dob(generalFunctions.convertTimeStamp(result.person.birthDate, false));
        inss(result.person.inss);
    });

    //Fill adresss
    datacontext.patientAddress(id).then(function(result) {
        var firstAdress = result[0];
        address(firstAdress.street);
        city(firstAdress.zip + " " + firstAdress.municipality);
        phone(firstAdress.cellPhoneNumber);
    });


    //datacontext.medicationEntries(id).then(function (result) {
    //    console.log("medicationEntries");
    //    console.log(result);
    //});


    //datacontext.careElements(id).then(function (result) {
    //    console.log("CareElements");
    //    console.log(result);
    //});
};

var vm = {
    personIsSelected: personIsSelected,
    personIsNotSelected: personIsNotSelected,
    name: name,
    sex: sex,
    dob: dob,
    inss: inss,
    address: address,
    city: city,
    phone: phone,
    activate: activate,      

};

return vm;
});
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from your activate, so it shouldn't be waiting on anything.  What are you seeing that makes you think it's waiting on the `activate`?

Comment: If i open my chrome development tools and check the network tab (calls to the server), I see that durandal waits until the call has finished, if I add for example 5 calls, it takes a while before the view is loaded.

Comment: Is the code you posted accurate in that you're not returning anything?  And what version of durandal are you using?  Also, you said it "waits until the call has finished" waits for what?

Comment: I pasted the full viewmodel ;) (And I use 2.0)

Comment: I'm still not clear what you think it's waiting for, your activate method is not returning anything therefore there is *nothing for durandal to wait on*.  Are you saying that the entire view does not render until the ajax request completes?

Comment: Yesh :(, it waits until everything is fetched, for example, if I have 5 calls, it waits unitl all 5 have finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the word return in-front of your datacontext.PersonData() call and that should show the view immediately... The only way that wouldn't work is if your datacontext.PersonData() is not returning anything until the data has been returned from the server.

```
var person = ko.observable();

var activate = function() {
     return datacontext.PersonData(person); 
}
```

If your PersonData is what's holding up your call, then pass in your person or whatever into your datacontext and set it on the success of the ajax call.

```
var PersonData(person) = function () {
    return $.ajax(function () { // do some ajax call
                    success: function (data) {
                        person(data);
                    });
}
```

Comment: dataContext.PersonData() is indeed a ajax call that returns the value:  return http.get(url, null, "GET", getToken(config.username, config.password, "GET", url)); 
But in the activatie method i have like 6 methods to get data, so how can I use the return then? If i use it the rest will not be executed

Answer (score 0):

Soo PW Kad, you made me think, 
I went looking in the http module and saw following thing:

get: function (url, query, type, header) {
            return $.ajax(url, {
                data: query, headers: { 'Authorization': header }, dataType: "json", crossDomain: true, type: type, async: false,            });
        },

ASYNC: FALSE

Sigh :)

Thanks for rubber ducking guys :)